# i have a code that acts as a journal for the user to make entries in, im having issues with flipping through it cause the entries are in a list

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, journal

So it is a python code and the user makes entries with the attributes date and content and it is automatically sorted by date old to now in a list. i want to be able to flip through the journal so i have one function for opening the journal (just printing list(0) however i cant quite make a function that flips the pages. i want to be able to flip forward by one page and the next time the user flips the page (in the same run) it will flip forward one more and so on. i cant get it to work with a while loop since i dont want all the entries printed at once so im a bit lost. i understand i must simply add 1 to the number within the list index im calling but im not sure how to do that and save it for the next time the user presses flip page. grateful for help

```
def bläddra_framåt(self):
    self.minnes_anteckningar.sort()
    antal_sidor = len(self.minnes_anteckningar)
    if antal_sidor < 1:
        print("du måste skriva något först")
    else:
        nuvarande_sida = 1
        antal_sidor = len(self.minnes_anteckningar) - 1
        if nuvarande_sida <= antal_sidor:
            sida = self.minnes_anteckningar[nuvarande_sida]
            print("detta är nästa sida:")
            print(sida)
            nuvarande_sida += 1
```

Comment: Have a variable `index` that starts at zero (the first page) and gets incremented by 1 when the user goes to the next page and decremented when the user goes back a page. You'll need to post your attempt to get much more help check out [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: grateful for the reply and i understand however since the code is for an assignment it is entirely in swedish and might be hard to comprehend